# How to get the current jupyter notebook servers in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can you get a list of the currently running Jupyter Notebook Servers in python?

There is a `jupyter-notebook` command to list the current notebook servers

```
machinename:~ username$ jupyter-notebook list
 http://localhost:8888 :: /Users/username/your/notebook/path
 http://localhost:8889 :: /Users/username/your/other/notebook/path
 ...
```

How can this be done in python without going to the command line and parsing the output?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Accessing a list of running notebook servers from python

The list of running notebook servers may be accessed from within python via the actual python `notebookapp` program by calling `list_running_servers()`.

```
from notebook import notebookapp
servers = list(notebookapp.list_running_servers())
print(servers)
```

---

```
[{u'base_url': u'/',
  u'hostname': u'localhost',
  u'notebook_dir': u'/Users/username/your/notebook/path',
  u'pid':123,
  u'port': 8888,
  u'secure': False,
  u'url': u'http://localhost:8888/'},
 ...
 {u'base_url': u'/',
  u'hostname': u'localhost',
  u'notebook_dir': u'/Users/username/your/other/notebook/path',
  u'pid': 1234,
  u'port': 8889,
  u'secure': True,
  u'url': u'http://localhost:8889/'}]
```

This also gives you more information than the command line interface.    \o/<sup><sup>-nice!</sup></sup>

Answer (score 8):

You can do it from the command line with the following command:

```
find `jupyter --runtime-dir` -mtime -5 | grep nbserver | xargs cat
```

`jupyter --runtime-dir` returns the directory where a Jupyter stores a lot of JSON metadata files about kernels and Jupyter servers.
The `-mtime` parameter of `find` makes it show only files modified within the last 5 days.

On my MacBook I get the following result:

```
{
  "base_url": "/",
  "url": "http://localhost:8888/",
  "port": 8888,
  "pid": 50017,
  "secure": false,
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "notebook_dir": "/Users/myusername"
}{
  "base_url": "/",
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "notebook_dir": "/Users/myusername",
  "password": false,
  "pid": 63644,
  "port": 8889,
  "secure": false,
  "token": "058fc6cbd6d793c6ddda420ff6d5d3c42819be526b68602d",
  "url": "http://localhost:8889/"
}
```

(I have two environments with different versions of Jupyter)

Comment: Thanks for the extra command detail. This does provide an output better than the text only output of my original command (i.e. `json`), however, I asked for a method to get the information without using the command line.  Original use case is to do this from within a python script.  No need to go outside the interpreter if we don't have too.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `jupyter notebook list` for your purpose. It lists all running servers:

```
<frankliuao/Volumes/Ao_HardDisk/$> jupyter notebook list
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8889/? 
token=476f392542ef41bc020cf26c2ddac0128ee42c0d3c542ac7 :: 
/Users/frankliuao/Downloads/
http://localhost:8888/? 
token=b1a33f34b80ddfa2476550671599b566131e3d875d9d4250 :: 
/Users/frankliuao/Desktop
```

If you want to get that information in Python you may use `popen` to execute a Shell command.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this notebook + httpserver if you can install jupyter server proxy on your Jupyter Notebook plateform

https://github.com/gbrault/jpjwidgets