# How to read localhost url in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm making a project on Jupyter notebook that requires me to keep track of the number in the localhost url, and I currently get this number by having a pop-up window where the user needs to types it in. However, I want to see if there's a way to skip this step and automatically get the url when the notebook runs. Does anyone know if there is a function or some other way that I can do this?

Edit: to clarify, when I open my Jupyter notebook, it runs in a Google Chrome window with the url localhost:8888 (or some other 4 digit number) followed by the path to the folder the notebook is in. I want to see if there is a way for the notebook to read that number or the entire url.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Where does the number come from?  Is that the server's port number?  Perhaps you should show an example.

Comment: "Automatically get the url" from what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/davidbrochart/ipyurl

Comment: might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475868/get-base-url-of-current-jupyter-server-ipython-is-connected-to

Comment: This is probably what you want (duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782255/how-to-get-the-current-jupyter-notebook-servers-in-python